# Working of program in Function Overloading

Tags: c++

I want to ask why this program does not generate a compile time error?

```
int Add(int x, int y){
    return (x+y);
}

double Add(double x, double y, double z){
    return (x+y);
}

int main()
{
    cout<<Add(5,6);
    cout<<Add(5.5,6.6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because it shouldn't. In the second call, the first method is ran.

Comment: the `double add` takes 3 parameters, and it would end up an error if u pass a `double` into and `int`. some common mistakes

Comment: @rockStar That's why the first method is called; It accepts two parameters, and the `double`s get converted to `int`s.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: yup, just saying that, coz he might have forgot it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Add(5,6);` calls `int Add(int x, int y)`. That is clear enough.

Now `Add(5.5,6.6)` looks for a proper matching function. It finds one with two arguments and one with three. Now it checks if it can use the function with two arguments. And indeed it can convert `double` to `int`. So it again uses `int Add(int x, int y)`.

If you would provide an `double Add(double x, double y)`, it would find two functions with two arguments and checks which one "matches best". This would then be `double Add(double x, double y)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because C++ defines an implicit conversion from `double` to `int`, which gets applied in the second call.

See `C++11[conv.fpint]§1`:

> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
Add(5.5,6.6);
```

it gets mapped to function signature

```
int Add(int x, int y);
```

so, 5.5 -> 5 and 6.8 -> 6 conversion takes place
and you get the answer as 11 (5 + 6).

Answer (score 0):

The solution comes down to the number of arguments:

For doubles you have

```
double Add(double x, double y, double z){
    return (x+y);
}
```

this function requires only/exactly 3 variables before it will be utilised, so when you specify only 2 arguments, there is only one choice available:

```
int Add(int x, int y){
    return (x+y);
}
```

Should you want to make it multi-purpose you would have to change it to

```
double Add(double x, double y, double z = 0.0){
    return (x+y+z);
}
```

This will allow you to add 2 or 3 doubles together as needed, as 2 double added is the same as 2 doubles added to 0.0.

The argument for z (`double z = 0.0`) is simply a default value declaration: most compilers work on the basis that, working right to left on the parameter list you can omit parameters which have defaults, therefore I could do the following:

```
double Add(double x= 0.0, double y=0.0, double z = 0.0)
```

and each of the following would be valid calls:

```
Add();
Add(1.0);
Add(1.1,2.2);
Add(1.1,2.2,3.3);
Add(1);
Add(1,2);
Add(1,2,3);
```

And the values which we do not specify will be in place by utilising the default values we defined earlier (0.0).

Example usage of modified function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double Add(double x, double y, double z = 0.0){
    return (x+y+z);
}
int main() {
    cout << Add(1.1,2.1,3.1) << endl;
    cout << Add(2,3) << endl;
    cout << Add(1.0, 2.12345) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps, but let me know if you need more information or detail :)

Answer (score 0):

Guys this will generate a compile error **'Add' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments** You need three arguments for the ADD functions- both for int and double- to be utilized.

While I appreciate your answers on this, you must understand that function overload in C++ done like this requires exact number of parameters to be specified in the calling.

Visual Studio won't allow u to compile the above source code. Pass three arguments to the calling of functions in main function.

.
.
.
    cout << Add(5,6,7) << endl;
    cout << Add(5.5,6.6,2) << endl;
.
.
.